# .NET DataGridView to show object fields

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a winforms application, which has a DataGridView. I want to be able to set DataSource of this DataGridView to an arbitrary IEnumerable, so that it shows all public properties AND fields on that object. By default DataGridView only shows properties

I do know how to refactor classes to convert field to property, but I would prefer to be able to do it without refactoring. Is there any sort of trick I could do on DataGridView, which would instruct it to show fields as if they were properties? Maybe I could use some library to convert objects within data source to their proxy where fields are wrapped?

**UPDATE:** thanks all for the input. Custom type descriptor is likely a most generic method, so I counted it as a correct answer. For my own purpose, I decided to go another way, converting the object to DataTable, like this:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
foreach (var o in (IEnumerable)data)
{
    var r = dt.NewRow();
    foreach (var f in o.GetType().GetFields())
    {
        if (!dt.Columns.Contains(f.Name))
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(f.Name);
        }
        r[f.Name] = f.GetValue(o);
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(r);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: It's technically not the DataGridView that doesn't allow this. It's the CurrencyManager class that is used internally that only allows properties and not fields. I can't think of a good way to do what you're asking.

Comment: If the grid is only for viewing, you can try using LINQ to convert the IEnumerable objects into Anonymous objects where you create the properties from the fields, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create subclass of `CustomTypeDescriptor` in order to override the `GetProperties()` method. Then you have to implement your own `TypeDescriptionProvider` class to set them in the `TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute` of desired class (which will be represented as row).
Example: [bind second-level properties](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnts/archive/2007/01/19/how-to-bind-a-datagridview-column-to-a-second-level-property-of-a-data-source.aspx?Redirected=true)

Here is my example:

**MyFieldsClass**

```
[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(MyTypeDescriptionProvider))]
internal class MyFieldsClass
{
    public int IntField;
    public double DoubleField;
}
```

**FieldPropertyDescriptor**

```
internal sealed class FieldPropertyDescriptor<TComponent, TField> : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private readonly FieldInfo fieldInfo;

    public FieldPropertyDescriptor(string name)
        : base(name, null)
    {
        fieldInfo = typeof(TComponent).GetField(Name);
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
    public override void ResetValue(object component) { }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return false; }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return typeof(TComponent); }
    }
    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return typeof(TField); }
    }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return fieldInfo.GetValue(component);
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        fieldInfo.SetValue(component, value);
        OnValueChanged(component, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

**MyCustomTypeDescriptor**

```
internal sealed class MyCustomTypeDescriptor : CustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public MyCustomTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor parent)
        : base(parent)
    {
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return GetProperties();
    }

    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return AddItems(base.GetProperties(),
            new FieldPropertyDescriptor<MyFieldsClass, int>("IntField"),
            new FieldPropertyDescriptor<MyFieldsClass, double>("DoubleField"));
    }

    private static PropertyDescriptorCollection AddItems(PropertyDescriptorCollection cols, params PropertyDescriptor[] items)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor[] array = new PropertyDescriptor[cols.Count + items.Length];
        cols.CopyTo(array, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++ )
            array[cols.Count + i] = items[i];
        PropertyDescriptorCollection newcols = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(array);
        return newcols;
    }
}
```

**MyTypeDescriptionProvider**

```
internal sealed class MyTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private ICustomTypeDescriptor td;

    public MyTypeDescriptionProvider()
        : this(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(MyFieldsClass)))
    {
    }
    public MyTypeDescriptionProvider(TypeDescriptionProvider parent)
        : base(parent)
    {
    }
    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        return td ?? (td = new MyCustomTypeDescriptor(base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance)));
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new List<MyFieldsClass>(new[] { new MyFieldsClass { IntField = 1, DoubleField = 10.0 } });
```

Comment: Example added: how to populate class's fields into `DataGridView`.