# How to set DataPropertyName to a property of a Inherited object in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I have a `DataGridView` and a `BindingList` and `BindingSource` to fill it.
The objects that i'm using to fill the `DataGridView` are like this:

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
     public int SomeProperty {get; set;}

     public MyBaseClass(int sp) {
         SomeProperty = sp;
     }
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
     public int AnotherProperty {get; set;}

     public MyDerivedClass(int sp, int ap):base(sp)
     {
         AnotherProperty = ap;
     }
}
```

My `DataGridView` can have a list with both of the objects, but i don't know how to set the `DataPropertyName` of the DataGrid column for the `AnotherProperty` in the inherited class.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22078353/2878550
It refers to the fields, but you can adapt it for your case by implementing a different logic in the `MyCustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties` method.

Answer (score 0):

So your `DataSource` is a collection of `MyBaseClass` objects?  What will it do with a `MyBaseClass` object that does not have that property?

One option is to make the property `virtual` on the base class and override it if necessary:

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
     public int SomeProperty {get; set;}
     public virtual int AnotherProperty {get; set;}

     public MyBaseClass(int sp) {
         SomeProperty = sp;
     }
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
     public MyDerivedClass(int sp, int ap):base(sp)
     {
         AnotherProperty = ap;
     }
}
```

Comment: My DataSource is a collection of MyBaseClass but also may contain some of MyDerivedClass too.

Comment: My point is what should be shown for the base class (or derived classes) that don't have that property?  Just a blank cell?  Would a virtual property on the base not work?

Comment: If the row is "of type" MyBaseClass, then that cell would be "----" and if the row is "of type" MyDerivedClass, then the cell would be the value corresponding to that property (int value).